# Why is this daily reminder function not working?

Tags: swift, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I'am trying to send local notifications to my user using the function below. They can manually select times with a toggle and that's when they are going to get notified. I am testing these times with my phone by setting the time manually in the phones settings, but the problem is that I only get the notification for 16:30, but it prints out that it set all the notifications. Here is the function:

```
func sendNotofication() {
    
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = Notification
    content.body = "Local Notification body!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    var dateComponentsm = DateComponents()
    dateComponentsm.hour = 0
    dateComponentsm.minute = 1
    
        
    var dateComponents2 = DateComponents()
    dateComponents2.hour = 1
    dateComponents2.minute = 30
        
        var dateComponents3 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents3.hour = 3
        dateComponents3.minute = 00
        
        var dateComponents4 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents4.hour = 4
        dateComponents4.minute = 30
        
        var dateComponents5 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents5.hour = 6
        dateComponents5.minute = 00
        
        var dateComponents6 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents6.hour = 7
        dateComponents6.minute = 30
        
        var dateComponents7 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents7.hour = 9
        dateComponents7.minute = 00
        
        var dateComponents8 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents8.hour = 10
        dateComponents8.minute = 30
        
        var dateComponents9 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents9.hour = 12
        dateComponents9.minute = 00
        
        var dateComponents10 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents10.hour = 13
        dateComponents10.minute = 30
        
        var dateComponents11 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents11.hour = 15
        dateComponents11.minute = 00
        
        var dateComponents12 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents12.hour = 16
        dateComponents12.minute = 30
        
        var dateComponents13 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents13.hour = 18
        dateComponents13.minute = 00
        
        var dateComponents14 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents14.hour = 19
        dateComponents14.minute = 30
        
        var dateComponents15 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents15.hour = 21
        dateComponents15.minute = 00
        
        var dateComponents16 = DateComponents()
        dateComponents16.hour = 22
        dateComponents16.minute = 30
   
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    
if reminders {
    print("reminders true")
    if first {
        let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponentsm, repeats: true)

        let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "first", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("Notifications 1 set \(dateComponentsm)")
            }
            
        }
    }
    if second {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents2, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "second", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm) { error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("Notifications 2 set \(dateComponents2)")
            }
            
        }
           
        }
    if third {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents3, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "third", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 3 set \(dateComponents3)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if fourth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents4, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "fourth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 4 set \(dateComponents4)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if fifth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents5, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "fifth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 5 set \(dateComponents5)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if sixth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents6, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "sixth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 6 set \(dateComponents6)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if seventh {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents7, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "seventh", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 7 set \(dateComponents7)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if eight {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents8, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "eight", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 8 set \(dateComponents8)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if nineth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents9, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "nineth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 9 set \(dateComponents9)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if tenth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents10, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "tenth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 10 set \(dateComponents10)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if eleventh {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents11, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "eleventh", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 11 set \(dateComponents11)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if twelfth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents12, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "twelweth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 12 set \(dateComponents12)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if thirteenth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents13, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "thirteenth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 13 set \(dateComponents13)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if fourteenth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents14, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "fourteenth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 14 set \(dateComponents14)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if fithteenth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents15, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "fithteenth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 15 set \(dateComponents15)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    if sixteenth {
            let triggerm = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents16, repeats: true)

            let requestm = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "sixteenth", content: content, trigger: triggerm)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestm){ error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("Notifications 16 set \(dateComponents16)")
                }
                
            }
        
        }
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { (notifications) in
        print("number of pending notifications \(notifications.count)")

                })
    
}
  }
```

Comment: Can it be that this removes some future ones? UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

Comment: Have you requested authorization to use the `UNUserNotificationCenter`? I don't see it anywhere in your code. Also, please explain what you mean by "sometimes I get a notification and sometimes not".

Comment: You might also want to only write down once the content of your many if clauses and have a part that is adapting to the input. A for loor going over all posible cases? It is no good Idea to write the same code several times, if you need to change something, here you need to do it 16 times. That is bad for you, you might forget something!

Comment: @Jelumar no that's not the problem, because I tried it without it and it still didn't work. And thanks for the advice, I will try to do it with a for loop

Comment: @Todd by  "sometimes I get a notification and sometimes not" I mean, that when I turn on all the notifications and on my phone I change the date 1 minute before the trigger was set and I wait for the activation time, I only get a notification once or twice and the `getPendingNotificationRequests` only prints out that there is 1 notifications pending

Comment: Do you get the "Notifications X set ..." printed for all the notifications you want? If not there might be a problem with the 16 bools and how they are set.

Comment: @Jelumar yes it printed them out

Comment: you could try out what you get for each UNCalendarNotificationTrigger you createwhen using its method nextTriggerDate(). And you might check here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger if the things you use actually do exactly what you expect them to.